# NSMutableArray objects string interpolation in SwiftUI Text View

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a NSMutableArray, with multiple objects, and I want to print the name of the objects in a simple Swiftui.Text.

`myobject1.name="name1"

myobject2.name="name2"

myobject3.name="name3"

myArray[myObject1, myObject2, myObject3]`

How can I print all the names from the 3 objects in a single Text()?

`Text(\(myArray.?))`

I want my text to look like= "name1+name2+name3"

Comment: Why an old NSMutableArray instead of the Swift native `Array` type? If it was the latter you could simply do `Text(myArray.map(\.name).joined(separator:"+"))`

Comment: I am using KMM, so the backend is fully kotlin

Comment: Then what about using a `for` loop in a computed property to generate the string from the array content?

Comment: And I am using RealmLists

Comment: How that for loop will look in and where I should place it? Before the body?

Comment: Like I said, create a computed property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let myArray = ["myObject1", "myObject2", "myObject3"]
    
var joined: String {
     myArray.joined(separator: "\n")
}
    
Text(joined)
```

[image]

```
var joined1: String {
    myArray.joined(separator: ", ")
}
Text(joined1)
```

[image]